# Does T-SQL MOVE actually move the database, or just copy?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm a bit confused over the T-SQL command MOVE. I have a statement saying:

```
MOVE 
N'Prod_Database_Data' 
TO 
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test_Database.mdf'
GO
```

The same statement is used on the log: Prod_Database_Log. I think the statement just makes a copy of the database and not actually moves the original database. Am I right or have I missed something fundamentally crucial?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no MOVE command.

There is the ["RESTORE" command with arguments "WITH MOVE"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

This deletes the old MDF and LDF files (if database already exists) and recreate the MDF/LDF files (and NDFs etc) where specified

Comment: Thanx! Just what I needed to know. It is (as you say) after a RESTORE command.